# How to invoke default template functional argument in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I want my template function

```
template<class function>
int probe(function call = [] (int a, int b) { return a+b; })
{
    return call(10, 10);
}
```

to be able to receive *pointers to functions* and invoke this function later. This excerpt is correct and the compiler does not complain on errors. Let's consider the such program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class function>
int probe(function call = [] (int a, int b) { return a+b; })
{
    return call(10, 10);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << probe([](int a,int b){ return a-b;});
}
```

The program outputs what I've expected: zero. However, I explicitly denoted for this call what a function I am passing - I mean about this lambda-expression in the parentheses `[](int a,int b){ return a-b;}`. That's fine until I pass nothing - the call `std::cout << probe();` is incorrect, however I've expected that the function will use default function `function call = [] (int a, int b) { return a+b; }`. So, how do I call the function that instance of this function will use default lambda-expression in the declaration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default function arguments don't contribute to template argument deduction. The compiler can't deduce `function` when no function argument is given explicitly, and so the call site cannot be matched to any function to call.

One pretty straightforward way to get your example to work, is to overload instead.

```
template<class function>
int probe(function call)
{
    return call(10, 10);
}

inline int probe() 
{ 
     return probe([] (int a, int b) { return a+b; }); 
}
```

Comment: sorry, what overload?

Comment: @AyratArifullin - There are two probe functions in my answer. I overloaded `probe` instead of using a default argument.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've thought that below is main :) Thank you. Now, I understand!

Comment: see, if I use ```std::cout << probe<std::function<int(int,int)>>();``` it does not produces errors. It works!

Comment: @AyratArifullin - Of course it works, you specified the very thing the compiler cannot deduce on its own, the type of the template argument.

Answer (score 2):

Another way could be add a default for the template parameter.

Obviously must be a type compatible with the default value for `call` (`decltype([] (int a, int b) { return a+b; })` doesn't works because every time you define a lambda is a different object).

```
template <typename function = std::function<int(int,int)>>
int probe (function call = [] (int a, int b) { return a+b; })
{
    return call(10, 10);
}
```

Now

```
probe();
```

works, if you remember to `#include <functional>`.

Otherwise you can define the default value for `call` before, save it in a constant so you can use `decltype()` (and no need to `#include <functional>`)

```
static const auto lam = [] (int a, int b) { return a+b; };

template <typename function = decltype(lam)>
int probe (function call = lam)
{
    return call(10, 10);
}
```